# Need help to build my selector

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-selectors, children

Here is my JS code:

```
<script>
var my_var = $(this).parent(); // not important what 'my_var' really is
</script>
```

I would like to create a **jQuery selector** to select **all children elements of 'my_var'** element **which have the class 'class_1' and 'class_2'**.

I know I have to use '>' for children but my problem is that I have 2 classes ('class_1' and 'class_2') and my basic element is defined by a var ('my_var').

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#" + my_var).children(".class_1.class_2")
```

If my_var is a jQuery element then just

```
my_var.children(".class_1.class_2")
```

Comment: Oh ok thank you! The second one is what I was looking for and the first is helpfull for future.
Thanks!

Comment: I supose it's because you have an extra quotation mark in the first line, after my_var. Your answer is correct anyway.

Comment: ah, I initially had "#my_var" because I didn't realize it was a variable, I thought it was the id

Comment: Am i the only one that sees that jQuery requires commas for multiple class selectors? Everyone keeps concatenating the class names. See http://www.jsfiddle.net/yZNqS/ (try with and without commas)

Comment: @Brad: except he wanted to target elements which have both classes, not one Or the other.

Comment: @Brad Christie, the OP said he wanted to get children which have the class 'class_1' AND 'class_2'. Putting commas between the class selectors will select children with 'class_1' OR 'class_2'. This is not a jQuery thing, it's a CSS thing.

Comment: Ah, that's my mistake. Good thing I'm not reading spec sheets this week, I'd be in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small typo fix (no need for double quotes after my_var):

```
jQuery("#" + my_var).children(".class_1.class_2")
```

Comment: Note my_var is not an id (string), but a jQuery object.